# Applying animation effects for angular2 animations effects

Tags: angular, animation, angular-animations

I am trying to apply animations to the md-card(trying to replicate the https://teradata.github.io/covalent/#/components/expansion-panel) ...I am able to get the view and apply the animations but the transition when a card is expanded/collapsed is smooth which i'm not able to get. I have made a demo here http://plnkr.co/edit/kvzSSbseT5cbOv054i2u?p=preview where the transition between states is fast.I am trying to implement the same kind of animation when my card in the demo is clicked...

```
animations: [
    trigger('animationState', [
        state('active', style({ height: '*' })),
        state('inactive', style({ height: '0px', display: 'none' })),
        transition('inactive => active', animate('150ms ease-out')),
        transition('active => inactive', animate('150ms ease-out'))
    ])
]
```

These are the animations i'm trying to apply.
can somebody please help me in getting such of animation effect which is in the above link?

Answer (score 0):

I just watched this tutorial on youtube.  It gives a good foundation in animation controls...

https://coursetro.com/posts/code/25/Understanding-Angular-2-Animations-Tutorial